# matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions

Tags: python, regression

my code is:

```
a = X.to_numpy()
pred_y = numpy.matmul(a, b)
resid_y = y - pred_y
```

see picture below for a and b:[image]

how can I fix this ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)
Thank you.

Comment: You can't use matmul with a matrix and a scalar... Maybe you just want `b * a` to scale the matrix

Comment: From the docs (emphasis mine): Parameters x1, x2: array_like Input arrays, _scalars not allowed_